# gson nested custom serializer

Tags: java, json, gson

I've a nested object that I cannot manage to serialize with gson. I made a custom serializer which is used with the parent object but with the child one I didn't manage to make it work.

So in my code below the custom serializer is used to serialize a `Team`. That works. In this team I have a list of `User` that I want to serialize as well. Unfortunately the method `addProperty(String a, String b)` askes for 2 strings (or a primitive) so I cannot add a property members which is of the class `User`.

Here is the code, first I create a `Gson` object and register the custom serializer for `Team`:

```
gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Team.class, new TeamSerializer())
            .create();
 gson.toJson(userData); // UserData instance.
```

This is the class that is gonna be serialized with the `Gson` object (I omitted irrelevant fields symbolized by //...):

```
public class UserData{
    public Team team;
    //...
}
```

This is the custom serializer where I cannot add the property `members`:

```
public class TeamSerializer implements JsonSerializer<Team>{
    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(Team src, Type type, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        JsonObject object = new JsonObject();
        object.addProperty("id", src.getIdteams());
        object.addProperty("name", src.getName());
        object.addProperty("tag", src.getTag());
        object.addProperty("picture", src.getProfilePic());
        //object.addProperty("members", src.getMembers());
        return object;
    }
}
```

This is the `Team` class:

```
public class Team implements Serializable {
    private long idteams;
    private String name;
    private String tag;
    private String profilePic;
    private List<User> members;
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Describe the generic relationships with [TypeToken](http://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/reflect/TypeToken.html) and use the context to transform the list:

```
TypeToken<List<User>> typeDescription = new TypeToken<List<User>>() {};
JsonElement members = context.serialize(src.getMembers(), typeDescription.getType());
object.add("members", members);
```

If *User* isn't a standard bean you may need a *TypeAdapter* for it too.

Comment: I just tried this and the compiler says that it is impossible to call serialize() on both List and TypeToken. It should be either just the list of the list and a type of type Type, not TypeToken... Do you by any chance know why?